# I keep getting the error of newUser.save is not a function, Next.js 13 api route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, next.js13

I am aiming to implement an OTP (One-Time Password) request process following a successful signup using the .save().then() method. However, when attempting to execute the code, I encounter a TypeError: 'newUser.save is not a function'."

This is my code

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
  const data = await req.json();
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_TOKEN);
  const sanity = {
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_KEY,
    dataset: "production",
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_TOKEN,
  };

  const clients = createClient(sanity);

  try {
    const users = await clients.fetch(
      `*[_type == 'user' && email == $email] [0]  `,
      {
        email: data.email,
      }
    );

    if (users) {
      return new Response(`User Already Exist`, {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt);
    const newUser = await clients.create({
      _type: "user",
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      phone: data.phone,
      password: passwordHash,
    });

    await newUser.save().then((result) => {
      OtpVerificationEmail(result)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })

    // await transporter.sendMail({
    //   ...mailOptions,
    //   subject: "",
    // });

    Cookies.set("user", {
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      phone: data.phone,
    });

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ data }), {
      status: 201,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(`${error}`, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};
```

I tried using .save() function but it is not working on next.js 13

Comment: Are you using this package: [sanity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/client) ?

Comment: Yes,
The request is okay but the error is coming from this code   await newUser.save().then((result) => {
      OtpVerificationEmail(result)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })